# Access the textfield of one controller from other controller

Tags: javafx

1st controller from i am trying to set the value:

```
public class NewProjectScreenController  implements Initializable,ControlledScreen {
   public String result;
    ScreensController myController;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */



     @FXML
     public void goToProjectUpdateScreen(ActionEvent event) {
            myController.setScreen(MainController.screen6ID);
         Session session = NewHibernateUtil.opensession();
        session.beginTransaction();

       Query queryResult = session.createQuery("from Project where ProjectId = 3 and RegistrationId= 1");
  java.util.List allUsers;
  allUsers = queryResult.list();
  for (int i = 0; i < allUsers.size(); i++) {
   Project project = (Project) allUsers.get(i);
   //System.out.println("Database contents delivered..."+ project.getProjectname()); 
   result=project.getProjectname();

  ProjectCreationScreenController.setText(result);

  }
```

2nd Controller:

```
public class ProjectCreationScreenController implements Initializable,ControlledScreen {

    ScreensController myController;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */


    @FXML
   private static TextField proname;
   public static void setText(String value) {
   proname.setText(value);
}  


    @FXML
    private TextField prodescription;

    @FXML
    private TextField OutputIntegration;

    @FXML
    private Button button;



     @FXML
       private void goBack(ActionEvent event) {
        myController.setScreen(MainController.screen5ID);
    }


        @FXML
       private void gotoSave(ActionEvent event) { 
           Project project = new Project();
        project.setProjectname (proname.getText());
        project.setProjectdescription(prodescription.getText());
       project.setOutputintegration(OutputIntegration.getText());
        Registration r= new Registration();
       r.setRegistrationid(3);
       project.setRegistration(r);
       ProjectModule.AddProject(project);
      // button.setDisable(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
       myController=screenParent;
    }

}
```

Actually  the problem here is I am getting the values from db but the problem is when i am trying to set the value in textfield,it is giving the Null pointer exception.

When i try to debug it , i am able to fetch the value from db and also in setext function, it is taking the exact value but the only problem is in setting the value in UI.

Using java fx and hsql

Comment: You cannot declare `@FXML`-injected fields as `static`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639881/javafx-how-to-use-a-method-in-a-controller-from-another-controller

Comment: I did not read the description but you are not supposed to access a node from one controller into another, you must access the values or pass the values.