# JavaFX: Communicating between parent and child pane's Controllers

Tags: java, javafx, controller, parent-child, pane

I have written a little programm, which is based on this cool [Framework from jewelsea](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130) 
.

It's about having a main pane and several child panes.

How can I now set up a communication between the Controllers?
If I wanted to change the value of a label on `childPane2`, from a Button on `childPane1` or the mainController, for example.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639881/javafx-how-to-use-a-method-in-a-controller-from-another-controller helps

Comment: Thanks, that really helped