# JavaFX, pass parameters between tabs controller

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, fxml, tabpanel

I looked for a solution anywhere before asking this question, if it already exists please report it.

In practice I have this situation:

[image: CLICK TO VIEW THE IMAGE]

**TabLayout.fxml**

```xml
<JFXTabPane fx:id="tabbedPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="500.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMinWidth="100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TAB.TabController" stylesheets="@tab.css">
<tabs>
  <Tab id="anagrafeTab" closable="false" text="Anagrafe">
    <content>
      <fx:include fx:id="anagrafeL" source="/application/Anagrafe/AnagrafeLayout.fxml"/>
     </content>
  </Tab>
  <Tab id="visiteTab" closable="false" text="Visite">
     <content>
        <fx:include fx:id="visiteL" source="/application/Visite/VisiteLayout.fxml"/>
     </content></Tab>
  <Tab id="latteTab" closable="false" text="Produzione Latte"> 
     <content>
        <fx:include fx:id="latteL" source="/application/Latte/LatteLayout.fxml"/>
     </content>
  </Tab>
  <Tab id="partiTab" closable="false" text="Parti" >
     <content>
         <fx:include fx:id="partiL" source="/application/Parti/PartiLayout.fxml"/>
     </content>
  </Tab>
</tabs>
</JFXTabPane>
```

A layout for every "include":

- `AnagrafeLayout.fxml`
- `VisiteLayout.fxml`
- `LatteLayout.fxml`
- `PartiLayout.fxml`

Than I have a model and a controller for every Layout but an unique caller.

```
public class Tab {

public Tab() {
    inizializza();
}

private void inizializza() {
    try {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Dati");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("insert.png")));

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("TabLayout.fxml"));
        JFXTabPane root = (JFXTabPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,660,430);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
        //ScenicView.show(scene);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

I need to pass an `ObservableList<Visite> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` to each controller.

I do not really know how to do, and I would not use a single controller because they are quite long classes.

**EDIT:**

**TABController.java**

```
public class TabController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TabPane tabbedPane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    assert tabbedPane != null : "fx:tabbedPane=\"in\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'TabLayout.fxml'.";

    tabbedPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ov, oldTab, newTab) -> {

        if(tabbedPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            tabbedPane.getScene().getWindow().setWidth(1171);
            tabbedPane.getScene().getWindow().setHeight(700);
        } else {
            tabbedPane.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
        }           
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT2**

The 4 tabs have, as mentioned above, each his own model class.
So I have 4 different lists, which are initially empty because they are filled dynamically since there is a table for each tab.
The lists are created when the tabPane is called by a different internships.
I need these lists because it may be the possibility of a previous load and I have to then pass this information to the controller.

In practice, this happens:

1)

Call the function insert that creates empty lists loaded from the tables in the tab. The data is then stored in a database at the close.

2)

Call the function displays that calls the function insert with a specific flag that creates lists and takes the data from the database and sends them to the tables that can then be modified.

I hope I was clear, I apologize for the ambiguity of the question precede

Now I'm solving in this way

```
public class TabController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TabPane tabbedPane;

@FXML
private VisiteController visiteLController;
private ObservableList<Visite> dataVisite = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Visite> dataDelVisite = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private LatteController latteLController;
private ObservableList<Latte> dataLatte = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Latte> dataDelLatte = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private PartiController partiLController;
private ObservableList<Parti> dataParti = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Parti> dataDelParti = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    assert tabbedPane != null : "fx:tabbedPane=\"in\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'TabLayout.fxml'.";

    tabbedPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ov, oldTab, newTab) -> {

        if(tabbedPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            tabbedPane.getScene().getWindow().setWidth(1171);
            tabbedPane.getScene().getWindow().setHeight(700);
        } else {
            tabbedPane.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
        }           
    });     

    visiteLController.setData(dataVisite, dataDelVisite);
    latteLController.setData(dataLatte, dataDelLatte);
    partiLController.setData(dataParti, dataDelParti);
 }
}
```

and the set method obviously changed for each controller

```
    public void setData(ObservableList<Visite> data, ObservableList<Visite> dataDel) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataDel = dataDel;
    liveSearh();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `TabController`? This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068243/share-model-with-nested-controller

Comment: Added :)
Now I look back at the link

Comment: Please clarify the question. What, exactly, does each controller need, and where do you create the data each needs, or have access to those data?

Comment: Ok, see now, I hope I was clear, I apologize for the ambiguity of the question precede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best bet here is to use a [controller factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) so that you can pass the list to the controllers when they are created by the `FXMLLoader`.

So first, define all your controllers so they have a constructor taking the observable list:

```
public class TabController implements Initializable {

    private final ObservableList<Visite> data ;

    public TabController(ObservableList<Visite> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    // existing code...
}
```

and, for example,

```
public class AnagrafeController implements Initializable {

    private final ObservableList<Visite> data ;

    public AnagrafeController(ObservableList<Visite> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    // existing code...
}
```

Now you need a controller factory, which is essentially a function that takes a `Class` and returns a controller of that class. This just needs a little reflection:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("TabLayout.fxml"));

ObservableList<Visite> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

loader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> controllerType) -> {
    try {
        Constructor<?>[] constructors = controllerType.getConstructors();
        for (Constructor<?>[] constructor : constructors) {
            if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 1 &&
                constructor.getParameterTypes()[0] == ObservableList.class)

                return constructor.newInstance(data);
            }
        }

        // no suitable constructor found, just use default:
        return controllerType.newInstance();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("Could not create controller:");
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return null ;
    }
});

JFXTabPane root = loader.load();

// ...
```

This will create an observable list (`data`) and the controller factory will ensure that if the controller class has a constructor taking an observable list as a parameter, `data` is passed in as that parameter.

When you use `<fx:include>` the same controller factory is used to create the controllers for the included FXML files, so the same list will be passed to those controllers too, assuming you define an appropriate constructor.

You can also consider a dependency injection framework for this, which basically automates the injection of objects into your controllers. [Afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) is a very nice JavaFX dependency injection framework.

Comment: Well, Tab Controller does not require data list, however, for each controlle I have to give a different list.
   Should I create a factory controllers for each controller class?
   And if I send two lists instead of one?
   I await your response, meanwhile I orient myself toward a solution that is present in the link you sent me; ie, in the class TabController I declare the controllers of the various controller classes and I call a setter present in the different controller classes.

Comment: OK, I assumed the problem was that you needed to share the data between the different controllers. If you have access to the lists in the `TabController`, why not just define a `setData(...)` method in each of hte other controllers and pass the list in from the `TabController`'s `initialize()` method?

Comment: was my initial solution just does not work for my mistake: I declared not properly the names of the controller variables.
I noticed thanks to the link you sent me at the beginning :)