# JavaFX: Binding does not work with included FXML

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, properties, binding

I want my included/embedded fxml-based controls to inform their containing objects (parent views) about changes in their states/properties. As you can see below I wrote a **Container.fxml** including a **View.fxml** plus the according to controller classes, named "Container.java" and "View.java".

When the textField of **ViewController.java** changes, its StringProperty 'textProperty_View' is updated. That seems to be working properly as the OnAction-handler is invoked as expected.

But the listener in the parent **ContainerController.java** does not fire though I bound its StringProperty to the StringProperty of **ViewController.java** and added a ChangeListener for this property.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.:

- I simplified the example by doing the same thing without `fx:include` to see if the binding works. It works. But not when I embed the view like in the described problem (see code below)
- Am using javafx-15-ea+3 and java11

**AppStarter.java**

```
public class AppStarter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Container.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**ContainerController.fxml**

```
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" 
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="gui.ContainerController">

      <fx:include source="View.fxml" fx:id="view"/>

<!-- <TextField fx:id="textFieldMain" prefWidth="200" onAction="#onActionMain"/>  -->

</HBox>
```

**ContainerController.java**

```
public class ContainerController implements Initializable {

    private final StringProperty textProperty_Main = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @FXML
    private ViewController viewController;

//    @FXML
//    void onActionMain(ActionEvent event) {
//        System.out.println("onActionMain " + viewController.getTextProperty_View());
//    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        textProperty_Main.bind(viewController.textProperty_ViewProperty());
        textProperty_MainProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                System.out.println("textProperty of Container changed to: " + getTextProperty_Main())
        );
    }

    public String getTextProperty_Main() {
        return textProperty_Main.get();
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty_MainProperty() {
        return textProperty_Main;
    }
}
```

**View.fxml**

```
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" 
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" 
      fx:controller="gui.ViewController">

     <TextField fx:id="textField" prefWidth="200" onAction="#onAction">Unset</TextField>

</HBox>
```

**ViewController.java**

```
public class ViewController {

    private final StringProperty textProperty_View = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @FXML
    void onAction(ActionEvent event) {
        textProperty_ViewProperty().setValue(textField.getText());
        System.out.println("textProperty of View changed to: " + textProperty_ViewProperty().getValue());
    }

    public String getTextProperty_View() {
        return textProperty_View.get();
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty_ViewProperty() {
        return textProperty_View;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as expected for me: I see updates for the text property in the `ContainerController` when the text changes.

Comment: java naming conventions, please ..

Comment: @James_D: Yes, I tried, but I did not work. The problem is, that the listener does NOT even get invoked. So changes within the handler-function are useless. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @kleopatra: Do you mean I missed one setter for the properties?! I left them out to save space in this post. Having them included did not make any difference. Or what convention do you mean?!

Comment: I was seeing the listener getting invoked. But I see the problem now. Answer imminent.

Comment: no, I mean exactly what I said: __do follow java naming conventions__  (hints: you don't and any search engine is your friend ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is a really frustrating one: JavaFX bindings use `WeakListener`s to implement the bindings. This means that if the bindings go out of scope, the listeners are eligible for garbage collection, and consequently may stop working. (In my setup, your code actually works, but if I invoke `System.gc()` somewhere, it immediately stops working.)

The only fix I can find for this is to explicitly retain a reference to the `ContainerController` in the application class (since the `ContainerController` has a reference to the `ViewController`, and the `ViewController` has a reference to the text field, this creates a path to the binding's listener via the listeners on the text field, etc.):

```
public class AppStarter extends Application {
    
    private ContainerController controller ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Container.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        this.controller = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for (a) the explanation and (b) your solution, James! It worked! Though I am wondering if there is maybe a different solution as I have have several levels of embedded controls and think that I generate a lot of "boilerplate" code just to pass values to the top level control.

Comment: @NeilArmstron9000 Use a MVC approach: share a single model instance with each controller and bind to properties in the model, instead of binding between different controllers. See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx/32343342#32343342

Comment: Thanks again for your advice! I tried it out and it works  BUT I am not sure if and how it really solves my problem. This is because my Container.fxml is containing an included fxml which is including another fxml. Is it possible to pass the model argument from my AppStarter.java to the control at the bottom level in one step without attaching controllers for every level? Or am I totally wrong and should I better use something like a depency injection framework?

Comment: @NeilArmstron9000 DI frameworks are always an option worth considering. Also note that if you set a `controllerFactory` on the FXML loader, the same factory will be used for loading included FXML files. This gives you the opportunity to provide a model  to controllers and nested controllers (though likely requires using reflection in the code for the controller factory). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37071740/2189127

Comment: I will try it out! From my point of view my main question in this post was answered. And as DI is a different topic this question could be closed. Thanks so much again for your advices!