# Accessing FX Controller then calling method which updates the label text (Synchronizing the FXML and controller ) [Issue]

Tags: java, javafx

A separate thread gets Controller through below line segment code

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    try 
    {
        loader.load();
    } catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error loading");
    }
    FXMLDocumentController controller = loader.getController();
```

Controller contains a method `dynamicUpdate(String data)` , Now I am calling this method from the thread where I have got the controller as follow.

```
controller.dynamicUpdate("hello from the thread"+count);
```

now here is the method in the controller: `FXMLDocumentController` :

```
public  void dynamicUpdate(String data)
{
    helloLabel.setText(data);
}
```

Where helloLabel is the id of the label and in the controller it's an instance variable
In xml it's inside pane:

```
  <Label fx:id="helloLabel" layoutX="182.0" layoutY="179.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="259.0" text="sdadsadasdsadasd" />
```

in Controller it's:

```
 @FXML
public Label helloLabel;
```

The issue is the method is being called and the console outputs are being print on the console but the text label is not being updated and neither any exception is being thrown. 
Any help, any reading will be very great !
Thank you

Comment: You're not displaying the FXML that contains the `ListView` (you don't even keep a reference to the result of calling `loader.load()`). So you're updating a `ListView` that isn't even displayed.

Comment: let me add more details

Comment: Sure... please do. I meant `Label` instead of `ListView`, btw (I was confusing this with a very similar question posted a little earlier).

Comment: For instance if I call same 'helloLabel.setText("Hello World")' it gets updates on a button click but it isn't from another method in the same controller i have tried with task and binding with property and then updating, it still doesn't works.

Comment: But you loaded the FXML (via `loader.load()`), which creates a new label (along with the rest of the UI defined in the FXML file), but *that label is never displayed*. So you don't see the results of changing its text.

Comment: but the xml contains the controller and the method is in that controller and the controller is again returned from the loader then it should be changed.

Comment: Again, the controller does change the text of the label (the one that is created when you call `loader.load()`), but (again) that label isn't displayed anywhere. So what do you expect to see?

Comment: What's the right way then

Comment: Hard to say without actually seeing enough code to know what you are doing. I assume you must be loading the FXML *and displaying the result* somewhere. You need a reference to the controller for the UI that is created when you load *and display* the FXML. You probably need to create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: Sure let me do that

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118025/javafx-pass-values-from-child-to-parent or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639881/javafx-how-to-use-a-method-in-a-controller-from-another-controller or more generally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Comment: Thank you I got your point, actually I was loading the xml twice and the changes are not made in the visible one,.

Comment: hello James_D, can you please add it as an answer so that I should accept it as answer it has solved my problem.

'But you loaded the FXML (via loader.load()), which creates a new label (along with the rest of the UI defined in the FXML file), but that label is never displayed. So you don't see the results of changing its text.