# How to Manipulate TableView from another Controller?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Note: AlbumAvailble is a ComboBox contains the Albums of a Singer.
     :AvailableSinger a ComboBox dontains the Singers.

I'm trying to display songs of an album in `TableView` in a different dialog which is "DisplaySongs.fxml".

I've tried to create a method in "DisplaySongs.java" controller of "DisplaySongs.fxml" to add all album songs to the table. so in the method which will display the dialog I've passed the selectedItem of AlbumAvailble and get the songlist of it.

the main window controller:

```java
@FXML
public void Display() {
    Dialog<ButtonType>DisplaySong = new Dialog<>();
    DisplaySong.initOwner(DisplayBorder.getScene().getWindow());
    DisplaySong.setTitle("DisPlay Songs");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("DisplaySongs.fxml"));
    try {
        DisplaySong.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    }catch (IOException E){
        E.getStackTrace();
    }
    DisplaySong.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);
    Optional<ButtonType> result = DisplaySong.showAndWait();
    if(result.isPresent()) {
        DisplaySongs controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.Display(AlbumAvailble.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    }
}
```

The Display of Songs controller:

```java
public class DisplaySongs {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Song> Songs ;

    public void Display(Album Alb) {
        Songs.getItems().addAll(Alb.getSongsList());
    }
}
```

The Song class:

```java
package MusicManiPulation;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Song {

    private SimpleStringProperty SongName = new SimpleStringProperty("") ;
    private SimpleStringProperty SongLength = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private LocalDate ReleasedDay ;

    public Song(String songName, String songLength, LocalDate releasedDay) {
        SongName.set(songName);
        SongLength.set(songLength);
        ReleasedDay = releasedDay;
    }

    public String getSongName() {
        return SongName.get();
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        SongName.set(songName);
    }

    public String getSongLength() {
        return SongLength.get();
    }

    public void setSongLength(String songLength) {
        SongLength.set(songLength);
    }

    public LocalDate getReleasedDay() {
        return ReleasedDay;
    }

    public void setReleasedDay(LocalDate releasedDay) {
        ReleasedDay = releasedDay;
    }
}
```

Album class:

```java
package MusicManiPulation;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Album {

    private String AlbumNam ;

    ArrayList<Song> SongsList ;

    public Album(String albumNam) {
        AlbumNam = albumNam;
        this.SongsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addNewSongToAlbum(String SongName , String SongLength , LocalDate ReleadsedDay) {

        boolean song = findSong(SongName);

        if (song) {
            return false;
        }
        SongsList.add(new Song(SongName , SongLength,ReleadsedDay));
        return true;
    }


    public boolean removeSong(String SongName){
        for(Song song :SongsList){
            if(song.getSongName().equalsIgnoreCase(SongName)){
                SongsList.remove(song);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean findSong(String SongName){

        for(Song song:SongsList){
            if(song.getSongName().equalsIgnoreCase(SongName)){
                return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getAlbumNam() {
        return AlbumNam;
    }

    public ArrayList<Song> getSongsList() {
        return SongsList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return AlbumNam;
    }
}
```

the getSongList method in Album class:

```java
public ArrayList<Song> getSongsList() {
    return SongsList;
}
```

Every time I press the "Display" Button the Table is Empty

Comment: You should ask a specific quesiton, also provide a [minimal complete reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.

Comment: I've edit the question @Calips

Comment: I suggest this answer : [JavaFX - How to use a method in a controller from another controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639881/javafx-how-to-use-a-method-in-a-controller-from-another-controller)

Comment: didn't get it  well to be honest

Comment: Add this method to your question please : `getSongsList()`

Comment: Done mate I've added it

Comment: Where is `SongsList` populated ? (By the way all names of variables should start with miniscule letter to make your code more readable)

Comment: it drives me crazy aaaaaa xD what do you mean ?

Comment: It's alright haha :D Where are you filling the `songsList` in the `album` variable

Comment: oh right it's in the addnewSongtoAlbum(); method

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra alright mate i will

Comment: You know what ? :D Put all your classes and fxml files code. I can't replicate the same example with only what you provided.

Comment: can i upload them and pass u a link ? it will take forever to copy and past them

Comment: And I meant, where do you call that `addnewSongtoAlbum()` method

Comment: Yes it's better to just upload them

Comment: read the help page that @Calips referenced in the first comment and act accordingly (no, don't upload anything anywhere - instead write a small example just for the purpose of demonstrating what you want to achieve and how it doesn't work as you expect)

Comment: there you go mate
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lDg31YTC2wmMN4A7sfH9ETkMgjsnKCO4

Comment: @Calips where are you haha xD?

Comment: @TigerTN Sorry for the late answer! Someone decided to evacuate my floor yesterday -_- Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Display(){

       Dialog<ButtonType>DisplaySong = new Dialog<>();
        DisplaySong.initOwner(DisplayBorder.getScene().getWindow());
        DisplaySong.setTitle("DisPlay Songs");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("DisplaySongs.fxml"));
        try {
            DisplaySong.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
        }catch (IOException E){
            E.getStackTrace();
        }
        DisplaySong.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);
        System.out.println("BEFORE Show");
        //Optional<ButtonType> result = DisplaySong.showAndWait(); //removed this line too
        DisplaySong.show();

      // if(result.isPresent()){ REMOVED THIS LINE.
     // YOU FORGOT THE CAST HERE :
         DisplaySongs controller = (DisplaySongs) fxmlLoader.getController(); 
            controller.Display(AlbumAvailble.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

}
```

Comment: Thanks Calips i figured it out yesterday as ur solution btw i would love to stay in contact with someone expert in java , coz i m newbie hope to learn more from U thanks again

Comment: I am not an expert XD but glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks again for real ^________^ i've spent almost 7 hours figuring it out yesterday

Comment: Calips could you check my last issue i mean for real i 've spent two days now resolving it xD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920892/how-to-display-my-data-from-file-in-tableview